# Tower of Hanoi - Long Int Can't handle result - Using timestamp on C++

Tags: c++, timestamp

i'm trying to solve a challenge on Urionlinejudge.com, the problem (see below) asks to calculate the time it takes to solve the Tower of Hanoi problem and output the hour (in HH:MM:SS format) that it ends.

The input is the number of disk and the output is the hour when it is solved (it's considered that each move takes one second).

I know that this algorithm grows in (2^n) - 1.

The major problem is that if the input is big the "long int" can't handle the result since it have a exponential growth.

I tried to solve this using a "for", and subtracting the number after 24 hours, since the problem don't asks how many days it takes, it only asks the hour on the day that the problem ends.

But, I exceeded the max runing time. What can I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 17)
    {
        n = pow(2, n);
        n--;
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            j *= 2;
            if (j >= 86400)
            {
                j -= 86400;
            }
        }
        n = j - 1;
    }
    int second, minute, hour;
    if (n >= 86400)
    {
        n = n % 86400;
    }
    if (n >= 3600)
    {
        hour = n / 3600;
        minute = n % 3600;
        if (minute >= 60)
        {
            second = minute % 60;
            minute = minute / 60;
        }
        else
        {
            minute = 0;
            second = n;
        }
    }
    else if (n >= 60)
    {
        hour = 0;
        minute = n / 60;
        second = n % 60;
    }
    else
    {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
        second = n;
    }

    cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0')
            << minute << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem:

(...)
The problem consists of 3 pins, and in the fist pin is sitting a stack of disks, one larger than the other. As we know, it is not allowed to place a larger disk above a smaller. This means that, to transfer one disk from the pile, one must first remove all the smaller ones first. Besides that, it is only allowed to move one disk at once.

The problem is solved when all disks from the first pin are transferred to the third pin.

We know that the monkeys started working at midnight (00:00:00), and that they work 24 hours per day, non stop, and they take at least 1 second to move each disk. Your task is to foresee the exact time of the day or night, in the format hh:mm:ss, of the earliest time possible the monkeys finish the game and the world ends.

Input
The input consists of a single line containing a single integer 0 < X < 10<sup>40</sup>, that is the number of disks in the starting stack.

Output
The output consists of a string in the format A:B:C, where 0 ≤ A < 24 e 0 ≤ B, C < 60 (HH:MM:SS) Format.

Source: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2681

Comment: "_The major problem is that if the input is big the "long int" can't handle the result since it have a exponential growth._" Did you try using `long long`?

Comment: You'll most likely have to build your own linked list in order to store the numbers with the amount of memory you'll have to be using.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, yes, but the problem requires something that stores (2^(10^40)-1)

Comment: @molbdnilo the timelimit is 1 (you can see the problem here: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2681)

Comment: @Luiz The limit is one what? Second? Millisecond? Minute?

Comment: @Luiz 1) Given sufficiently large datatype - the solution is trivial. Hence, the task is to find a way to workaround limitations of the datatypes. 2) Don't use `pow` to calculate the powers of integers, due to possible precision loss.

Comment: I fixed the exponentiation in the question, so you don't have to go to the page to notice that the upper limit is not 1040.

Comment: For the exponent, write your own limited "big int" implementation based on `vector<int>`. The only operations you need are "is zero", "is even",  "divide by two" and "subtract one". The result doesn't need anything bigger than `int`.

Comment: I couldn't stop thinking about the problem... :/ You don't need any datatype larger than 32-bit integer, nor you need big integer library. The answer should be the time of day, and the question doesn't care which day it is. Hence, you only need to calculate `2^n - 1 (mod seconds-in-a-day (= 24 * 60 * 60))`. And, from maths we know that `(a * b) (mod n)` = `(a (mod n) * b (mod n)) (mod (n)`, which you can use in your calculations.

Comment: @molbdnilo . The problem dont show the unit it measures the timelimit. Thank you for editing the question, I didn't see that it was showing 1040

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I will try your solution

Comment: @molbdnilo, it's in seconds, the limit is 1 second

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I tried this:   
 if (n < 17){
       n = pow(2,n);
      n--;
   }else{
       int j = ((pow(2,n)) % 86400)
but got a compiler error

Comment: @Luiz 1) "_2) Don't use pow to calculate the powers of integers, due to possible precision loss._" What you are observing is a side effect of trying to invoke modulo operator, that is undefined for doubles. 2) That is not what I suggested. With my suggestion, you wouldn't need to use `pow` at all. That's why I wrote a comment, instead of an answer: I don't want to write all the code for you. I gave you the idea for an algorithm. It's up to you to implement it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius hmm, ok. I will try to not use pow, i'm thinking on how to do it instead of using the for

Comment: @Luiz What's wrong with using `for`? It would have 1040 iterations at most.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius it's 10^40 iterations, not 1040, with this it exceeds the time limit

Comment: @Luiz Oh, I missed that. Then, there must be a possibility to increase the performance even further. Note: even simply raising to such power, would exceed the time limit, hence, there must be a way to reduce the iterations necessary.